# Redirecionar o usuário a página especifica

Tags: javascript, html

Ainda estou aprendendo JavaScript sei que tem como fazer com js mais não sei como executar, tenho 3 inputs do tipo radio, como posso redirecionar o usuario a uma página dependendo de qual campo o usuário clicar? As paginas a serem redirecionadas  ao clicar no botão submit seriam firm.html, confort.html e firm2.html

```
<div class="questionario-form">
    <div class="cards cards-final checkbox-img-text checkbox-video d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="capsule-cards">
           <div class="card card-video">
                <label for="colchao-firme">
                    <input value="firm.html" type="radio" id="pagina_colchao_firme" name="colchao" />
                    <img src="assets/images/questionario/final-step/248x248.png"    >
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="card-texto">
               <p class="titulo">Colchão de Mola Firm 26</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="capsule-cards">
            <div class="card card-video">
                <label for="colchao-firme">
                    <input value="confort.html" type="radio" id="colchao_confort_page" name="colchao" />
                    <img src="assets/images/questionario/final-step/248x248.png"    >
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="card-texto">
                <p class="titulo">Colchão de Mola Comfort 26 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="capsule-cards">
            <div class="card card-video">
                <label for="colchao-firme">
                    <input value="firm2.html" type="radio" id="colchao-firme" name="colchao" />
                    <img src="assets/images/questionario/final-step/248x248.png"    >
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="card-texto">
               <p class="titulo">Colchão de Mola Comfort 26</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui descobrir a base de pesquisas, ao invés de pegar o valor das inputs pelo **id**(que era o que eu estava fazendo), melhor pegar pelo **name**, então adicionei em cada input um name como por exemplo: name="pages" e criei uma função para redirecionar, em seguida colocando o onclick no botão, segue exemplo:

**Botão:**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <buttom class="action submit btn botao-primario btn-sucess" onclick="redirect()">Ver resultado</buttom>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
function redirect() {
    var pagina_colchao = document.querySelector('input[name="pages"]:checked').value;
    location.href="file:///C:/Nova%20pasta/index.php/"+pagina_colchao;
}
```

Com isso ele pega o valor de qualquer uma das três inputs e ao clicar no **submit** me redireciona para a página correspondente a input selecionada.
Espero ter ajudado
Abraços!